# LINQ: joining to table and returning wrong data

Tags: c#, linq

I am joining `Table A` and `Table B` and I want to return `Table B` which are common both tables.

But below query returning 2 times of whole table data of `Table B`

```
 var speCommonData = from commData in context.SpeCommonData
                join commonInfo in context.SpeCommonDataZipInfo on commData.SpeManuscriptNum equals commonInfo.SpeManuscriptNum
                where commData.Status == "WITHDRAWAL"
                select context.SpeCommonDataZipInfo.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue, because you call `context.SpeCommonDataZipInfo.ToList()`in the Select statement, Select just `commonInfo` to get data from `Table B`, like the following code :

```
 var speCommonData = (from commData in context.SpeCommonData
                join commonInfo in context.SpeCommonDataZipInfo on commData.SpeManuscriptNum equals commonInfo.SpeManuscriptNum
                where commData.Status == "WITHDRAWAL"
                select commonInfo).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.